# Query external tuples list embedded within a SQL query

Tags: python, tuples

I have to run a sql query that grabs the values only if two conditions are true. So for example, I need to grab all the values where `asset=x` and `id_name=12345`. There are about 10k combinations between asset and `id_name` that I need to be able to query for using sql. Usually I would just do the following:

`select * from database where id_name IN (12345)`

But how do I make this query when two conditions have to be true. `id_name` has to equal 12345 AND asset has to equal x.

I tried turning the list i need into tuples like this:

`new_list = list(scams[['asset', 'id_name']].itertuples(index=False, name=None))`

which gives me a list like this:

```
new_list = (12345, x), (32342, z)...etc.
```

Any suggestions would be great. Thanks!

Comment: ***"`id_name` has to `equal 12345 AND asset` has to `equal x`."***: Have you tried to phrase it like this?

Comment: Only problem is there are some duplicates for each values, like there can be: (12345, x), (12345,y) - so the combination between the two is what is key.

Comment: Can you make your SQL database do the work? multiple where conditions is what SQL is good at ...SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE <condition1> AND <condition2> AND ....

Comment: **"there are some duplicates"***: The tuple `(12345, x)` is not equal to `(12345,y)`

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding you need to query or fetch records based on a combination of two filters. Also you have around 10K combinations. Here is a simple SQL based solution.
Create a new column in the same table or build a temp table/view with a new column say "column_new". Populate the concatenated value of id_name and asset in the new column. You can use a concatenation function based on the database.  Example in SQL server use CONCAT(column1,column2).
Now you can write your SQL as `select * from database where colum_new IN ("12345x","32342z");`.
Note : You can also use a "-" or "|" between column 1 and column 2 while doing a concatenation.